# What ActiveX controls does gmail use in IE9?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, active-directory

Gmail says that ActiveX controls needs to be enabled, whenever I go there using IE9.  ActiveX **is** enabled, but only for approved plugins, and I'm wondering if it's worth approving whatever it needs, or if it's better to just switch browsers or use the old view.

Comment: Google to my knowledge does not use ANY ActiveX controls on ANY of its services.  I have some pretty strict security settings and I don't get any prompt on any version I have tried( 6,7,8,9,10 ).

Comment: if you google for "gmail activex ie9", you'll find quite a few people complaining about it.  And google has a page about  it, http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=10973